# C# Datagridview change row color based on condition only first 1000 records

Tags: c#, datagridview, backcolor

i have a little problem with my datagridview. I am filling the Datagridview with my records from the db.

But i want to change the back- and forecolor in a specific condition. It works fine but only with the first 1000 records and the problem is i have more than 10.000 records. Did i have a wrong event?

I'd be grateful for a better solution.

Best regards

my code:

```
private void dataView_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    foreach(DataGridViewRow row in dataView.Rows)
    {
        int value = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[2].Value);

        if(value == 1)
        {
            row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Orange;
        }
        else
        {
            row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This event is raised to allow you to format a cell. You're looping the whole collections of rows each time this event is raised. You just need to check whether the current `e.ColumnIndex` matches the Column you care about and change the BackColor of the corresponding Cell. No looping.

Comment: The current Row is `dataView.Rows[e.RowIndex]`.

Comment: @Jimi you are correct that he is looping the collection repeatedly and shouldn't be doing so. But he wants to change the row's style and not just he cell. He shouldn't be using the `CellFormatting` event to style the row, he will be repeating the logic to style the row for every cell as it calls the `CellFormatting` event.

Comment: @Jimi It was tested, and I also proposed the `DataBindingComplete` event if OP wants to keep the loop.

Comment: @quaabaam That can work when setting the initial state. If this format needs to be applied in *real time* (when the values change for other reasons or by user intervention), you need something else. So, possibly this event is not the one that is actually needed. Anyway, since RowPostPaint/RowPrePaint can work, IMO that's enough (you also avoid to perform the same operation twice when the datasource is bound).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CellFormatting` event is not the best option in your case. Your for loop is causing you to iterate over your data multiple times.

You can use the `RowPrePaint`, `RowPostPaint` or the `DataBindingComplete`  events for your scenario.

Using the `RowPrePaint` will allow you to color the row and leave open the option to apply additional cell level styling for individual cells.

```
 private void dataView_RowPrePaint(object sender, DataGridViewRowPrePaintEventArgs e)
 {
     DataGridViewRow row = dataView.Rows[e.RowIndex];
     if (Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[2].Value) == 1)
     {
         row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Orange;
     }
     else
     {
         row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
     }
 }
```

If you choose to keep your loop then you can use the `DataBindingComplete` event.

```
private void dataView_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataView.Rows)
    {
        int value = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[2].Value);
        if (value == 1)
        {
            row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Orange;
        }
        else
        {
            row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@quaabaam

thank you the first solution worked fine for me. Can i change 2 Cells with this event? like this:

```
private void DataGridView1_RowPrePaint(object sender, DataGridViewRowPrePaintEventArgs e)
        {
            DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
            //Secili olanlarin rengini degisdiriyo
            if (Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["Secili"].Value) == 1)
            {
                this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightSalmon;
                this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Black;
            }
            else
            {
                //Aktiv olmiyanlari kirmizi yapiyo
                if (Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["IsActive"].Value) == 1)
                {
                    this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
                    this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                }
                else
                {
                    this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.White;
                }
            }
        }
```

***Edit:***

i have now another problem.. Some of the first 1000 records are blacked out. I dont know why. I am using the function that i posted here.

Image: [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qCRc.png)